# Android - Stopping a thread using a while loop

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, udp

Weird problem that seems to have been mentioned a few times on here. I have a thread, have used AsyncTask also, and I am trying to make it stop running, on the users request.
So, naturally, I use a boolean in the while loop. The thread always sees that boolean as true, even when it prints false elsewhere.

Code is below and any help is appreciated!

```
/**
 * Opens new socket and listens on the specified port until a user stops the thread, the logview is updated with messages
 */
public void run() {
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    Log.e("Text2Server", "Starting Server");
    this.running = true;
    while(this.running) {
        Log.i("Text2Server", "Server should be running: " +  running);
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {   
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            final String fromIP = new String(receivePacket.getAddress().toString());
            final int fromPort = receivePacket.getPort();
            final String received = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            Date now = new Date();
            final String logput = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(now) + " - Message from: " + fromIP + " through Port: " + fromPort + " with Message: " + received;
            Log.i("Text2Server", logput);
            //All UI Operations are done in this thread
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    logTextView.append(logput);
                }                   
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    serverSocket.close();
}

public void stopThread() {
    this.running = false;
    Log.i("Text2Server", "Stopping Server, value is now: " + running);
}
```

Calling stopThread() makes it false, but the thread still goes into the while and prints out true. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling stopThread?

Comment: From an activity, I create an instance of the thread, set it running in that activity and then call stopThread() when the user presses a button

Comment: In the log you show the value of "running" instead of "this.running"...

Comment: yep, tried that. They are both the same value, I just posted midway through checking to see if it made a difference. Even declared running as volatile, to be sure.

Comment: You sure it hasn't just blocked on `serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);`?

Comment: Nope, because the server continues to receive messages from the client and prints them fine.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

1) You have spawned more than one thread and have closed only one of them.

2) You call `stopThread` before the thread starts running.

3) The thread has queued up many `logTextView.append(logput)` calls on the UI thread and therefore *appears* to be still running afterwards.

Comment: Maybe add a log output after the while loop to double check the third possibility.

Comment: Thanks, the log output for the 3rd possibility still shows, although it does not seem to update the textview, but that is another issue.
Only one thread is spawned by the activity and stop thread is only called after at least one message has been received. It is a weird one.